# why this javascript code don't work after i reload part of my page with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, reload

I have 3 files with php and js. in first file i load some information and show it to user, then user can change them. for show other information to user i reload part of my page with some code that they are in second php file. i put them in `<div id='show_album'>my data</div>` and change them with second php file.
for first run my javascript code work fine, but after reloading part of page it never work. what must i change in code that it work after reloading?!

this is part of code that can reload div element with ajax:

```
<select onchange="showList('showalbum.php?change=',this.value,'show_album')"><option value='1'>1</option> <option value='2'>2</option></select>
```

in this part of code that in first page i reload my div element with new data.
then in new data i have something like this:

```
<a href="albums/album1/SAM_2676.jpg" rel="lightbox">size of picture: 460*345</a>
```

that show picture link to user and when user click on it, with javascript i show it to user on this page and on my other information that user can close it.but now this rel="lightbox" don't work and when user click on link, this picture open in same window.

this is my javascript code and in `<head>` i define it:

```js
/*
 Table of Contents
 -----------------
 Configuration
 
 Functions
 - getPageScroll()
 - getPageSize()
 - pause()
 - getKey()
 - listenKey()
 - showLightbox()
 - hideLightbox()
 - initLightbox()
 - addLoadEvent()

 Function Calls
 - addLoadEvent(initLightbox)
*/

//
// Configuration
//

// If you would like to use a custom loading image or close button reference them in the next two lines.
var loadingImage = './LightBox/loading.gif';
var closeButton = './LightBox/close.gif';





//
// getPageScroll()
// Returns array with x,y page scroll values.
// Core code from - quirksmode.org
//
function getPageScroll(){

 var yScroll;

 if (self.pageYOffset) {
  yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
 } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop){  // Explorer 6 Strict
  yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
  yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
 }

 arrayPageScroll = new Array('',yScroll) 
 return arrayPageScroll;
}



//
// getPageSize()
// Returns array with page width, height and window width, height
// Core code from - quirksmode.org
// Edit for Firefox by pHaez
//
function getPageSize(){
 
 var xScroll, yScroll;

 if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) { 
  xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
  yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
 } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
  xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
  yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
 } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
  xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
  yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
 }
 
 var windowWidth, windowHeight;
 if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
  windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
  windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
 } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
  windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
  windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
 } 
 
 // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
 if(yScroll < windowHeight){
  pageHeight = windowHeight;
 } else { 
  pageHeight = yScroll;
 }

 // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
 if(xScroll < windowWidth){
  pageWidth = windowWidth;
 } else {
  pageWidth = xScroll;
 }


 arrayPageSize = new Array(pageWidth,pageHeight,windowWidth,windowHeight) 
 return arrayPageSize;
}


//
// pause(numberMillis)
// Pauses code execution for specified time. Uses busy code, not good.
// Code from http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/1602
//
function pause(numberMillis) {
 var now = new Date();
 var exitTime = now.getTime() + numberMillis;
 while (true) {
  now = new Date();
  if (now.getTime() > exitTime)
   return;
 }
}

//
// getKey(key)
// Gets keycode. If 'x' is pressed then it hides the lightbox.
//

function getKey(e){
 if (e == null) { // ie
  keycode = event.keyCode;
 } else { // mozilla
  keycode = e.which;
 }
 key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();
 
 if(key == 'x'){ hideLightbox(); }
}


//
// listenKey()
//
function listenKey () { document.onkeypress = getKey; }
 

//
// showLightbox()
// Preloads images. Pleaces new image in lightbox then centers and displays.
//
function showLightbox(objLink)
{
 // prep objects
 var objOverlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
 var objLightbox = document.getElementById('lightbox');
 var objCaption = document.getElementById('lightboxCaption');
 var objImage = document.getElementById('lightboxImage');
 var objLoadingImage = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
 var objLightboxDetails = document.getElementById('lightboxDetails');

 
 var arrayPageSize = getPageSize();
 var arrayPageScroll = getPageScroll();

 // center loadingImage if it exists
 if (objLoadingImage) {
  objLoadingImage.style.top = (arrayPageScroll[1] + ((arrayPageSize[3] - 35 - objLoadingImage.height) / 2) + 'px');
  objLoadingImage.style.left = (((arrayPageSize[0] - 20 - objLoadingImage.width) / 2) + 'px');
  objLoadingImage.style.display = 'block';
 }

 // set height of Overlay to take up whole page and show
 objOverlay.style.height = (arrayPageSize[1] + 'px');
 objOverlay.style.display = 'block';

 // preload image
 imgPreload = new Image();

 imgPreload.onload=function(){
  objImage.src = objLink.href;

  // center lightbox and make sure that the top and left values are not negative
  // and the image placed outside the viewport
  var lightboxTop = arrayPageScroll[1] + ((arrayPageSize[3] - 35 - imgPreload.height) / 2);
  var lightboxLeft = ((arrayPageSize[0] - 20 - imgPreload.width) / 2);
  
  objLightbox.style.top = (lightboxTop < 0) ? "0px" : lightboxTop + "px";
  objLightbox.style.left = (lightboxLeft < 0) ? "0px" : lightboxLeft + "px";


  objLightboxDetails.style.width = imgPreload.width + 'px';
  
  if(objLink.getAttribute('title')){
   objCaption.style.display = 'block';
   //objCaption.style.width = imgPreload.width + 'px';
   objCaption.innerHTML = objLink.getAttribute('title');
  } else {
   objCaption.style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  // A small pause between the image loading and displaying is required with IE,
  // this prevents the previous image displaying for a short burst causing flicker.
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){
   pause(250);
  } 

  if (objLoadingImage) { objLoadingImage.style.display = 'none'; }
  objLightbox.style.display = 'block';

  // After image is loaded, update the overlay height as the new image might have
  // increased the overall page height.
  arrayPageSize = getPageSize();
  objOverlay.style.height = (arrayPageSize[1] + 'px');
  
  // Check for 'x' keypress
  listenKey();

  return false;
 }

 imgPreload.src = objLink.href;

    var e = document.getElementById('gand');
    e.style.display = 'none';
 
}





//
// hideLightbox()
//
function hideLightbox()
{
 // get objects
 objOverlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
 objLightbox = document.getElementById('lightbox');

 // hide lightbox and overlay
 objOverlay.style.display = 'none';
 objLightbox.style.display = 'none';
 
 // disable keypress listener
 document.onkeypress = '';

    var e = document.getElementById('gand');
    e.style.display = 'block';
}




//
// initLightbox()
// Function runs on window load, going through link tags looking for rel="lightbox".
// These links receive onclick events that enable the lightbox display for their targets.
// The function also inserts html markup at the top of the page which will be used as a
// container for the overlay pattern and the inline image.
//
function initLightbox()
{
 
 if (!document.getElementsByTagName){ return; }
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

 // loop through all anchor tags
 for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
  var anchor = anchors[i];

  if (anchor.getAttribute("href") && (anchor.getAttribute("rel") == "lightbox")){
   anchor.onclick = function () {showLightbox(this); return false;}
  }
 }

 // the rest of this code inserts html at the top of the page that looks like this:
 //
 // <div id="overlay">
 //  <a href="#" onclick="hideLightbox(); return false;"><img id="loadingImage" /></a>
 // </div>
 // <div id="lightbox">
 //  <a href="#" onclick="hideLightbox(); return false;" title="Click anywhere to close image">
 //   <img id="closeButton" />
 //   <img id="lightboxImage" />
 //  </a>
 //  <div id="lightboxDetails">
 //   <div id="lightboxCaption"></div>
 //   <div id="keyboardMsg"></div>
 //  </div>
 // </div>
 
 var objBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
 
 // create overlay div and hardcode some functional styles (aesthetic styles are in CSS file)
 var objOverlay = document.createElement("div");
 objOverlay.setAttribute('id','overlay');
 objOverlay.onclick = function () {hideLightbox(); return false;}
 objOverlay.style.display = 'none';
 objOverlay.style.position = 'absolute';
 objOverlay.style.top = '0';
 objOverlay.style.left = '0';
 objOverlay.style.zIndex = '90';
  objOverlay.style.width = '100%';
 objBody.insertBefore(objOverlay, objBody.firstChild);
 
 var arrayPageSize = getPageSize();
 var arrayPageScroll = getPageScroll();

 // preload and create loader image
 var imgPreloader = new Image();
 
 // if loader image found, create link to hide lightbox and create loadingimage
 imgPreloader.onload=function(){

  var objLoadingImageLink = document.createElement("a");
  objLoadingImageLink.setAttribute('href','#');
  objLoadingImageLink.onclick = function () {hideLightbox(); return false;}
  objOverlay.appendChild(objLoadingImageLink);

  var objLoadingImage = document.createElement("img");
  objLoadingImage.src = loadingImage;
  objLoadingImage.setAttribute('id','loadingImage');
  objLoadingImage.style.position = 'absolute';
  objLoadingImage.style.zIndex = '150';
  objLoadingImageLink.appendChild(objLoadingImage);

  imgPreloader.onload=function(){}; // clear onLoad, as IE will flip out w/animated gifs

  return false;
 }

 imgPreloader.src = loadingImage;

 // create lightbox div, same note about styles as above
 var objLightbox = document.createElement("div");
 objLightbox.setAttribute('id','lightbox');
 objLightbox.style.display = 'none';
 objLightbox.style.position = 'absolute';
 objLightbox.style.zIndex = '100'; 
 objBody.insertBefore(objLightbox, objOverlay.nextSibling);
 
 // create link
 var objLink = document.createElement("a");
 objLink.setAttribute('href','#');
 objLink.setAttribute('title','براي بستن کليک کنيد');
 objLink.onclick = function () {hideLightbox(); return false;}
 objLightbox.appendChild(objLink);

 // preload and create close button image
 var imgPreloadCloseButton = new Image();

 // if close button image found, 
 imgPreloadCloseButton.onload=function(){

  var objCloseButton = document.createElement("img");
  objCloseButton.src = closeButton;
  objCloseButton.setAttribute('id','closeButton');
  objCloseButton.style.position = 'absolute';
  objCloseButton.style.zIndex = '200';
  objLink.appendChild(objCloseButton);

  return false;
 }

 imgPreloadCloseButton.src = closeButton;

 // create image
 var objImage = document.createElement("img");
 objImage.setAttribute('id','lightboxImage');
 objLink.appendChild(objImage);
 
 // create details div, a container for the caption and keyboard message
 var objLightboxDetails = document.createElement("div");
 objLightboxDetails.setAttribute('id','lightboxDetails');
 objLightbox.appendChild(objLightboxDetails);

 // create caption
 var objCaption = document.createElement("div");
 objCaption.setAttribute('id','lightboxCaption');
 objCaption.style.display = 'none';
 objLightboxDetails.appendChild(objCaption);

 // create keyboard message
 var objKeyboardMsg = document.createElement("div");
 objKeyboardMsg.setAttribute('id','keyboardMsg');
 objKeyboardMsg.innerHTML = 'براي بستن کليد  <kbd>x</kbd> را فشار دهيد';
 objLightboxDetails.appendChild(objKeyboardMsg);


}




//
// addLoadEvent()
// Adds event to window.onload without overwriting currently assigned onload functions.
// Function found at Simon Willison's weblog - http://simon.incutio.com/
//
function addLoadEvent(func)
{ 
 var oldonload = window.onload;
 if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){
     window.onload = func;
 } else {
  window.onload = function(){
  oldonload();
  func();
  }
 }

}



addLoadEvent(initLightbox); // run initLightbox onLoad
```

and i have css for this js that it is not importat but i write it here:

```css
#lightbox {
 background-color: #eee;
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
 border-right: 2px solid #666;
}

#lightboxDetails {
 font-size: 0.8em;
 padding-top: 0.4em;
}

#lightboxCaption {
 float: left;
}

#keyboardMsg {
 float: right;
}

#closeButton {
 top: 5px;
 right: 5px;
}

#lightbox img {
 border: none;
 clear: both;
}

#overlay img {
 border: none;
}

#overlay {
 background: url(../LightBox/overlay.png);
}

* html #overlay {
 background-color: #000;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src="../LightBox/overlay.png", sizingMethod="scale");
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
 opacity: 0.7;
}
```

i think this code just run one time on window.load() and after i reload part of page it can't load again and don't work.

how i can resolve this problem?
tnks for reading my question...

Comment: need to initialize your lightbox code after new elements inserted or use event delegation

Comment: how i can do this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Because to new html elements added after you need to recall all functions that work with it, for example recall functions that is called on document is created

Answer (score 0):

When you get result from ajax and put it on html page, after write `initLightbox();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `initLightbox()` here **and change them with second php file. for first run my javascript**

But you not write that code and I can't help you.

I can say only, put initlightbox after code where you receive response with ajax after lines where you insert new html elements.